# How to dynamically get database name and server name in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

This is a stored procedure that I want to be able to choose database dynamically.

Not sure how I would do that...

```
Declare @JobNumber varchar (25)=417132

Select 
    s.jobnumber, 
    Count(s.firstName) AS [firstNameCounts], 
    Count(s.lastName) AS [lastNameCounts], 
    Count(s.Address1) As [address1Counts], 
    Count(s.address2) - Count(address2) AS [address2Counts], 
    Count(s.City) AS [cityCounts], 
    Count(s.State) AS [stateCounts], 
    Count(s.Zip) AS [zipCounts], 
    Count(jb.inHomeDate) AS [inHomeDateCounts]
INTO 
    #Actual 
FROM
    [s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133].[dbo].[tblStandardFinal] s
INNER JOIN 
    [s-printstream].[tdSchedule2].[dbo].[tblJobTicketActions] jb ON jb.psFlagJobNumber =s.jobNumber  ## Heading ##
WHERE
    jobNumber = @jobnumber
GROUP BY 
    jobNumber


CREATE TABLE #Dummy
( 
    jobNumber INT,
    firstName VARCHAR(100),
    lastName VARCHAR(100),
    address1 VARCHAR(100),
    address2 VARCHAR(100),
    city VARCHAR(100),
    state VARCHAR(100),
    Zip VARCHAR(100),
    inHomeDate date
) 

INSERT INTO #Dummy (jobNumber, firstName, lastName, address1, address2, city, state, Zip, inHomeDate)
VALUES ('417133', 'JoJo', 'Marshal', '154 East Bailey Road', 'null', 'Chicago', 'IL', '60125', '04-25-2017'),
       ('417133', 'JoJo', 'Marshal', '154 East Bailey Road', 'null', 'Chicago', 'IL', '60125', '04-25-2017'),
       ('417133', 'JoJo', 'Marshal', '154 East Bailey Road', 'null', 'Chicago', 'IL', '60125', '04-25-2017')


 Select 
     d.jobnumber, 
     Count(d.firstName) AS [firstNameCounts], 
     Count(d.lastName) AS [lastNameCounts], 
     Count(d.Address1) As [address1Counts], 
     Count(d.address2) - Count(d.address2) AS [address2Counts], 
     Count(d.City) AS [cityCounts], 
     Count(d.State) AS [stateCounts], 
     Count(d.Zip) AS [zipCounts], 
     Count(D.inHomeDate) AS [inHomeDateCounts]
 INTO 
     #ProductionData 
 FROM
     #Dummy d
 GROUP BY 
     d.jobnumber


Select P.jobNumber,A.firstNameCounts,P.firstNameCounts,(P.firstNamecounts)*100/A.firstNameCounts AS Percentage,A.lastNameCounts,P.lastNameCounts, (P.lastNameCounts)*100/A.lastNameCounts AS Percentage,
A.lastNameCounts,P.lastNameCounts, (P.lastNameCounts)*100/A.lastNameCounts AS Percentage,A.address1Counts,P.address1Counts, (P.address1Counts)*100/A.address1Counts AS Percentage,
A.address2Counts,P.address2Counts, ISNULL (100*P.address2Counts/NULLIF(A.address2Counts,0),0) AS Percentage, A.CityCounts,P.cityCounts, (P.cityCounts)*100/A.cityCounts AS Percentage,
A.stateCounts,P.stateCounts, (P.stateCounts)*100/A.stateCounts AS Percentage, A.zipCounts,P.zipCounts, (P.zipCounts)*100/A.zipCounts AS Percentage, 
A.inHomeDateCounts,P.inHomeDateCounts, (P.InHomeDateCounts)*100/A.inHomeDateCounts AS Percentage
from #Actual A
Inner Join #ProductionData P
ON A.jobNumber=P.jobNumber

Drop Table #Actual
Drop Table #Dummy
Drop Table #ProductionData
```

This is the stored procedure that I want to be able to choose database dynamically. How would I do that?

Comment: use Dynamic Query on your `select into #actual` query